# How to plot a histogram with a custom distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

In an old statistics textbook, I found a table of a distribution of ages for a country's population:

```
        Percent of
 Age    population
------------------
 0-5         8
 5-14       18
14-18        8
18-21        5
21-25        6
25-35       12
35-45       11
45-55       11
55-65        9
65-75        6
75-85        4
```

I wanted to plot this distribution as a histogram in R, with the age ranges as breaks and the percent of population as the density, but there didn't seem to be a      straightforward way to do it. R's `hist()` function wants you to supply the individual data points, not a pre-computed distribution such as this.

Here's how I went about it.

```
# Copy original textbook table into two data structures
ageRanges <- list(0:5, 5:14, 14:18, 18:21, 21:25, 25:35, 35:45, 45:55, 55:65, 65:75, 75:85)
pcPop <- c(8, 18, 8, 5, 6, 12, 11, 11, 9, 6, 4)
# Make up "fake" age data points from the distribution described by the table
ages <- lapply(1:length(ageRanges), function(i) {
    ageRange <- ageRanges[[i]]
    round(runif(pcPop[i] * 100, min=ageRange[1], max=ageRange[length(ageRange)-1]), 0)
})
ages <- unlist(ages)
# Use the endpoints of the age class intervals as breaks for the histogram
breaks <- append(0, sapply(ageRanges, function(x) x[length(x)]))
hist(ages, breaks=breaks)
```

It seems like there has to be a less verbose/hacky way of going about it.

*EDIT*: FWIW, here's what the resulting histogram looks like:

[image: histogram]

Comment: If you already have the frequencies, and they're already binned, then just make a barplot.

Comment: @Marius: Won't the bars have equal width? This distribution has breaks of unequal length.

Comment: @PaulSmith - it's not incorrect as such, a histogram with the frequencies is perfectly valid. The `hist` function allows both counts or density by changing the `freq=FALSE/TRUE` input.

Comment: @thelatemail You're absolutely correct, I deleted my previous comment and updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should get what you want:

```
test <- read.table(textConnection("age popperc
0-5 8
5-14 18
14-18 8
18-21 5
21-25 6
25-35 12
35-45 11
45-55 11
55-65 9
65-75 6
75-85 4"),header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

midval <- sapply(strsplit(test$age,"-"),function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
breakval <- strsplit(test$age,"-")
breakval <- as.numeric(c(sapply(breakval,head,1),tail(unlist(breakval),1)))
hist(rep(midval,test$popperc),breaks=breakval)
```

[image]

You can also define your own object of `class` histogram and then just `plot` that if you just want to plot the frequencies not the densities:

```
# define the histogram object and plot it
histres <- list(
breaks=breakval,
counts=test$popperc,
mids=midval,
xname="ages",
equidist = TRUE
)
class(histres) <- "histogram"
plot(histres)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm glad to see a way to construct a `histogram` object, but the outcome has the same problem as @agstudy -- the heights of the bars in a histogram are not equal to the percents if the intervals of the bins are not the same, as is true in this example.

Comment: On the first code sample, I get an error on OS X in both 2.1.something and 3.0.1: Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "") : need finite 'ylim' values. Any ideas? Other than changing the data a bit (exactly the same form though), I entered the code exactly the same.

Comment: @SpankyQuigman - I couldn't be sure w/out more info. I'd recommend just doing `head(test)` and `summary(test)` and looking if anything is out of order.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did as you suggested and don't see anything untoward: http://pastebin.com/s2e1rbwa (the exact code I ran is here: http://pastebin.com/vpwXbaSR). I also ran this on 64-bit Windows 7 and R 3.0.1 with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comment use a `barplot`. You can specify width in a `barplot`

```
barplot(pcPop,  width = seq(0,85,5),space=0)
```

Comment: This won't work, because the density needs to be distributed across the bin as well. The heights will be incorrect.

Comment: @PaulSmith What do you mean by density needs to be distributed across the bin as well?

Comment: Sorry, that's not very clear -- if the intervals of the bins are not the same length, as is the case here, then the height of the bar is not equal to the percent. The bars should have area as if the percents were spread evenly over the each interval.