# Generating histogram that can calculate percent recovered

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have the following dataset called df:

```
  Amp Injected Recovered Percent less_0.1_True
  0.13175 25.22161274 0.96055540 3.81 0
  0.26838 21.05919344 21.06294791 100.02 1
  0.07602 16.88526724 16.91541763 100.18 1
  0.04608 27.50209048 27.55404507 100.19 0
  0.01729 8.31489333 8.31326976 99.98 1
  0.31867 4.14961918 4.14876247 99.98 0
  0.28756 14.65843377 14.65248551 99.96 1
  0.26177 10.64754579 10.76435667 101.10 1
  0.23214 6.28826689 6.28564299 99.96 1
  0.20300 17.01774090 1.05925850 6.22 0
  ...
```

Here, the less_0.1_True column flags whether the Recovered periods were close enough to Injected period to be considered a successful recovery or not. If the flag is 1, then it is a succesful recovery. Based on this, I need to generate a plot (Henderson & Stassun, the Astrophysical Journal, 747:51, 2012) like the following:

[image: Period Recoverability vs. Period]

I am not sure how to create a histogram like this. The closest I have been do reproduce is a bar plot with the following code:

```
breaks <- seq(0,30,by=1)
df <- split(dat, cut(dat$Injected,breaks)) # I make bins with width = 1 day
x <- seq(1,30,by=1)

len <- numeric() #Here I store the total number of objects in each bin
sum <- numeric() #Here I store the total number of 1s in each bin

for (i in 1:30){
n <- nrow(df[[i]])
len <- c(len,n)

s <- sum(df[[i]]$less_0.1_True == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
sum <- c(sum,s)
}

percent = sum/len*100 #Here I calculate what the percentage is for each bin
barplot(percent, names = x, xlab = "Period [d]" , ylab = "Percent Recovered", ylim=c(0,100))
```

And it generates the following bar plot:

[image: Barplot]

Obviously, this plot does not look like the first one and there are issues such as it does not show from 0 to 1 like the first graph (which I understand is the case because the latter is a bar graph and not a histogram).

Could anyone please guide me as to how I may reproduce the first figure based on my dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to the problem in StackOverflow. I guess the solved question was worded differently than mine and so I could not find it when I was looking for it initially. The solution is here: [How to plot a histogram with a custom distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721375/how-to-plot-a-histogram-with-a-custom-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code I get errors. You need to use `border = NA` to get rid of the bar borders:

```
set.seed(42)
hist(rnorm(1000,4), xlim=c(0,10), col = 'skyblue', border = NA, main = "Histogram", xlab = NULL)
```

[image]

Another example using `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]